# Condicional WHERE con ID de Session

Tags: php, mysqli

Hola como están tengo una consulta que me parte la cabeza en dos: tengo el siguiente código que me llama información de una tabla de empleados y todo ok si pongo en la sentencia el id manual, pero quiero poner en el condicional WHERE el ID de Sesión con el cual me logueo en el PHP para llamar los datos de ese empleado pues ahora mismos sin el WHERE trae todos los datos de la tabla espero me piedan ayudar.

```
<?php  
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['identificacion'])) {
        header('Location: login.php');
    }elseif(isset($_SESSION['identificacion'])){
        include 'model/conexion.php';
        **$sentencia = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM laboral WHERE emp_id = '86061155';");**
        $empleado = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        //print_r($empleado);
    }else{
        echo "Error en el sistema";
    }


    
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Lista de empleado</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Bienvenido: <?php echo $_SESSION['identificacion'] ?></h1>
        <a href="cerrar.php">Cerrar Sesión</a>
        <h3>Lista de empleado</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Código</td>
                <td>Apellido paterno</td>
                <td>Apellido materno</td>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Parcial</td>
                <td>Final</td>
                <td>Promedio</td>
                <td>Editar</td>
                <td>Eliminar</td>
            </tr>

            <?php 
                foreach ($empleado as $dato) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $dato->emp_id; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dato->emp_nombre; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dato->emp_cargo; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dato->emp_salario; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dato->emp_ingreso; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dato->emp_vencimiento; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dato->emp_tipcontra; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $dato->emp_lugexp_id; ?></td>
                        
                        <td><a href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $dato->emp_id; ?>">Editar</a></td>
                        <td><a href="eliminar.php?id=<?php echo $dato->emp_id; ?>">Eliminar</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
            
        </table>    
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y ¿Como tienes la consulta que falla?

Comment: Suponiendo que el identificador es el id solo habria que cambiar `emp_id = '86061155'` por `emp_id = '".$_SESSION['identificacion']."'`

Comment: @LaFortuna Por eso hay que esperar a ver como EL la tiene.

Comment: @Excorpion Es cierto, esa identificacion debe ser su username, pero le dara para pensar y solucionarlo.

Comment: ¿Cuál es concretamente ese problema tan grande que te parte la cabeza en dos y que no mencionas de una forma clara? ¿Qué es lo que falla? ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Has depurado la variable o elemento que falla tratando de mostrarlo con `var_dump` por ejemplo?

Comment: Gracias lograste resolver mi duda perfecto! @LaFortuna :)

Answer (score -1):

No hay suficiente información en tu pregunta así que puedo solamente suponer que esta es la situación: al momento de logear un usuario es que se obtiene la variable *$_SESSION['identificacion']*, el valor de la cual (supongo) viene la tabla de usuarios. De esa misma tabla puedes obtener el valor del ID del usuario que, (sigo suponiendo) sería algo como: $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = *id_de_la_tabla_usuarios*. Esa variable es la que debes usar en tu consulta.

Comment: Las respuestas no deben basarse en suposiciones, por lo que debes comentarle en ese caso. Todos los demás estamos a la espera de más información, sino, la pregunta será cerrada.